# How do I change the sbt colors?

Tags: scala, sbt

I like the colours sbt produces but I would like to change them (blue on black doesn't work well for me).

How do I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What platform and terminal are you on?

I'm guessing color coding is implemented through ANSI escape codes and you may need to override the meaning of those colors in your terminal (see https://superuser.com/questions/294440/how-can-i-redefine-the-way-ansi-colors-are-shown-in-a-terminal-emulator-in-linux for an example).

Similarly putty terminal lets you redefine ANSI colors in the Windows/Colours preference section.

Comment: You are right, example: 
`[info] ←[32m- test_degreeCount←[0m`
`[info] ←[32m- test_degreeNodeSeq←[0m`

Comment: I'm using a unix terminal so I suspect you are correct. I will try to find out which codes are being used.